# proper borders multi page long table latex

Tags: longtable

I am preparing a document in latex and have to insert a long table. The table spans over two pages. While formatting the table I am not getting continuous borders. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: if there is an error in your code then someone will be able to suggest how to fix it but they will need to see the code, please add a small complete document to your question that shows the problem. (unless the issue is that you are using vertical lines and the booktabs package, in which case the lines are intentionally broken)

Comment: I would say that if you read the documentation and follow that, your problem will disappear.

Comment: why not let us have a look at the compilable code starting with `\documentclass` and finishing with `\end{document}` and a screenshot of the table